# Getting rid of menu items on a custom taxonomy

Tags: admin

I have made up a custom taxonomy and it works great but in the admin menu I get the normal categories and normal tags showing up along side the custom categories and custom tags (see image) is there a way to only show the custom cats and custom tags?

[image: Admin menu items showing custom posts and categories]

So keeping "Event Cats" and "Event Tags" but getting rid of "Categories" and "Tags" on the menu.

Thanks

code:

```
            function event_post_example() {

                register_post_type( 'event_type',

                    array('labels' => array(
                        'name' => __('Events Posts', 'baretheme'),
                        'singular_name' => __('Event Post', 'baretheme'),
                        'all_items' => __('All Event Posts', 'baretheme'),
                        'add_new' => __('Add New Event Post', 'baretheme'),
                        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event Type', 'baretheme'),
                        'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'baretheme' ),
                        'edit_item' => __('Edit Post Types', 'baretheme'),
                        'new_item' => __('New Post Type', 'baretheme'),
                        'view_item' => __('View Post Type', 'baretheme'),
                        'search_items' => __('Search Post Type', 'baretheme'),
                        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found in the Database.', 'baretheme'),
                        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'baretheme'),
                        'parent_item_colon' => ''
                        ), /* end of arrays */
                        'description' => __( 'This is the example event post type', 'baretheme' ), /* Custom Type Description */
                        'public' => true,
                        'publicly_queryable' => true,
                        'exclude_from_search' => false,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'menu_position' => 9,
                        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png',
                        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'event_type', 'with_front' => false ),
                        'has_archive' => 'event_type',
                        'capability_type' => 'post',
                        'hierarchical' => false,

                        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky')
                    ) /* end of options */
                ); /* end of register post type */


                register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'event_type');

                register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'event_type');

            }


                add_action( 'init', 'event_post_example');

                register_taxonomy( 'event_cat',
                    array('event_type'),

                    array('hierarchical' => true,
                            'name' => __( 'Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
                            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
                            'all_items' => __( 'All Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
                            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
                            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event Category:', 'baretheme' ),
                            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
                            'update_item' => __( 'Update Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
                            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
                            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Event Category Name', 'baretheme' )
                        ),
                        'show_admin_column' => true,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event-slug' ),
                    )
                );

                register_taxonomy( 'event_tag',
                    array('event_type'), this */
                    array('hierarchical' => false,
                        'labels' => array(
                            'name' => __( 'Event Tags', 'baretheme' ),
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
                            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Event Tags', 'baretheme' ),
                            'all_items' => __( 'All Event Tags', 'baretheme' ),
                            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
                            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event Tag:', 'baretheme' ),
                            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
                            'update_item' => __( 'Update Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
                            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
                            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Event Tag Name', 'baretheme' )
                        ),
                        'show_admin_column' => true,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                    )
                );e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your code I suspect, as there are really many errors in your code. I'm going to list them

Firstly, you are registering your custom post type inside a function that you hook to `init`, which is fine. Then you register your taxonomies outside that function. What the reason bhin that is, I don't know. You should register both your taxonomies and custom post type inside your function, as your taxonomies are registered to your custom post type

Secondly, [`register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) looks like this. The `$object_type` parameter, although taking an array or a string can just be a string, as you are only registering your taxonomy to **one** custom post type

Thirdly, in the `event_cat` taxonomy, this line `'labels' => array(` is missing, breaking everything

Fourthly, in the `event_tag` taxonomy, there is this piece `this */` of nothingness, which also breaks your code

Lastly, if this was your code, you should have not registered category and tags. Here is the code that registered categories and tags

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'event_type');
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'event_type');
```

So, after all of this, your code should be

```
function event_post_example() {

register_post_type( 'event_type',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Events Posts', 'baretheme'),
        'singular_name' => __('Event Post', 'baretheme'),
        'all_items' => __('All Event Posts', 'baretheme'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New Event Post', 'baretheme'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event Type', 'baretheme'),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'baretheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Post Types', 'baretheme'),
        'new_item' => __('New Post Type', 'baretheme'),
        'view_item' => __('View Post Type', 'baretheme'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Post Type', 'baretheme'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found in the Database.', 'baretheme'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'baretheme'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ), /* end of arrays */
    'description' => __( 'This is the example event post type', 'baretheme' ), /* Custom Type Description */
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_position' => 9,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png',
    'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'event_type', 'with_front' => false ),
    'has_archive' => 'event_type',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,

    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky')
    ) /* end of options */
); /* end of register post type */

register_taxonomy( 'event_cat','event_type',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Event Categories', 'baretheme' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event Category:', 'baretheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event Category', 'baretheme' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Event Category Name', 'baretheme' )
    ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event-slug' ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy( 'event_tag','event_type',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Event Tags', 'baretheme' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Event Tags', 'baretheme' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Event Tags', 'baretheme' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event Tag:', 'baretheme' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event Tag', 'baretheme' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Event Tag Name', 'baretheme' )
    ),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    )
);
}

add_action( 'init', 'event_post_example');
```